# Javascript not working within HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Hey so I have an HTML page with this part of javascript within it that updates local storage:

```
<script src="../../Website/json/modernizr.js" >
        var button = document.getElementById("btnsave");

        button.addEventListener("click", function(){
            if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
            // window.localStorage is available!
                var drinksElement = document.getElementById("drinks");

                for (var i = 0; i < drinksElement.length-1; i++) {
                    localStorage["box" + i] = drinksElement[i].value;
                }
            } else {
                // no native support for HTML5 storage :(
            }
        });        
</script>
```

But for some reason it's not doing what it's supposed to. The page loads up fine without any errors seen on the console. If I copy and paste this script into the developer console, then click the button to update local storage, local storage will update, but only once, then it seems to "forget" this javascript function. If I copy and paste this into console then type "button", It will show the button variable. I can keep typing "button" and it will keep showing the button variable until I click on the button and it updates the local storage. After that, calling button again returns a reference not defined error.

Thanks in advance, this has been troubling me for quite some time.

Comment: Paste the exact error being returned.

Comment: This is the error that is returned:

VM120:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: button is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1

I don't get this error if I copy and paste the script into console though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `modernizr` reference and the javascript code should be in different script tags.

```
<script src="../../Website/json/modernizr.js" ></script> 
<script> 
        var button = document.getElementById("btnsave");

        button.addEventListener("click", function(){
            if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
            // window.localStorage is available!
                var drinksElement = document.getElementById("drinks");

                for (var i = 0; i < drinksElement.length-1; i++) {
                    localStorage["box" + i] = drinksElement[i].value;
                }
            } else {
                // no native support for HTML5 storage :(
            }
        });        
</script>
```

As per the spec - **[`<script>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element)**,

> If there is a src attribute, the element must be either empty or contain only script documentation that also matches script content restrictions.

Also, as per [@QuasimodosClone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024716/javascript-not-working-within-html-page/38024762#comment63490728_38024762), *However it is displayed as simple HTML content by user agents not understanding the `<script>` tag*.

Comment: I can't believe I completely overlooked this! Thanks so much. Really helps to have someone else review code sometimes.

Comment: Even I missed it at first. :). Happens. Please accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: To become a good answer to the world, it should be explained, that the content between `<script src="..."> some content </script>` never is executed due to a given `src` attribute. However it is displayed as simple HTML content by user agents not understanding the `<script>` tag. So one could write something like "Your browser does not support scripts" there.

Comment: Well, I thought it *is* pretty evident that the asker knew this. I'd still add it to the asnwer. Thanks for your suggestion.